# SELECT RADIANS(47) vs SELECT RADIANS(47.0)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, radians

Ran into this issue with a Store Locator that I'm building. The Radians function returns a Zero (0) when executing SELECT RADIANS(47), but it returns 0.83... when executing SELECT RADIANS(47.0).

The ending result is causing the distance calculated by the sql statement to be Zero (0). I'm running on the following system:

- OS Name  Microsoft(R) Windows(R) Server 2003 Standard x64 Edition
- Version  5.2.3790 Service Pack 2 Build 3790
- System Model VMware Virtual Platform
- System Type  x64-based PC
- SQL Server   Microsoft SQL Server 2005

Here is the SQL statement that I'm using the radians function with.

```
SELECT TOP 15 i.* FROM ( 
    SELECT [id],[storeName],[storeNumber],[latitude],[longitude],

    ROUND((3959*acos(cos(radians([latitude])) * cos(radians( 47 )) 
    * cos(radians( -122.915 ) - radians([longitude])) + sin(radians([latitude])) 
    * sin(radians( 47 )))) , 2) AS distance 

    FROM [Public].[dbo].[stores] WHERE [latitude] <> 0 AND [longitude] <> 0 
) i WHERE distance < '50' ORDER BY i.distance
```

Answer (score 3):

It works as designed.
According documentation this function returns the same type as parameter.
The same with simple operator:
select 5/2, 5.0/2 -- returns 2 and 2.5